# Intent passing bundle object finishes the current activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, serialization, bundle

I am passing a arraylist of custom object using intent from one activity to another using bundle object by serializing the pojo class and it is also working in some devices like micromax. But whereaas in some devices like samsung, sony, etc., the activity finishes instead of opening a new activity. Any help or assistance would help me a lot since i am struggling from this for more than two days. I know this is a rare phenomenon but i dont know the solution to solve. My code is as follows

In **Activity A** am sending the values as:

```
Intent whoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this,MainActivity2.class);
Bundle whoIntentObject = new Bundle();
whoIntentObject.putSerializable("array", abstractValues);
whoIntent.putExtras(whoIntentObject);
startActivity(whoIntent);
finish();
```

In **Activity B** am receiving the values as:

```
ArrayList<MyDetails> mArrayListResponse = (ArrayList<MyDetails>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(array);
```

Comment: activity A finishes because you call `finish();`

Comment: thats fine but if i remove finish() also same thing is happening

Comment: put your logcat.Check any exception arises

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable time for viewing my question. I found my own solution after analysing the complete code and memory leakage issues in android. Atlast i came to the solution that app is occupying more spaces in Heap so that it fails to pass the arraylist with custom object to another activity through intent. It worked for some phones with higher end configuration whereas in lower end it fails to push into the activity, so instead it again started the same activity.